# Signal 11(Coredump) from "catgets"

Tags: c++, c

Segmentation fault at catgets..
GDB Report:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003935430cc6 in catgets () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Code:

```
char *msg_log( int msg_len,int msg_switch,int severity,int classi,const char *File,int Line,nl_catd cd,int msg_set,int msg_no,const char *dftfmt...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, dftfmt);
    char *fp, *lp;
    int checked = 0, len;
    fp = strchr(dftfmt, '%');
    if (fp != NULL) 
    {
        lp=strrchr(dftfmt, '%');
        if(fp==lp && *(fp+1)=='s') 
        {
            fp=va_arg(args, char *);
            checked = 1;
            len=strlen(dftfmt);
            if(strlen(fp)>BUFLEN-len) 
            {
                fp[BUFLEN - len] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
    char catbuf[BUFLEN];
    char *fmt=catgets(cd,msg_set,msg_no,(char *)dftfmt);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is C code, you should remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Your function receives a lot of unused parameters: `msg_len`, `msg_switch`, `severity`, `classi`, `File`, `Line`.  If you ignore the first 6 parameters to a function, it is presumably because they are used in later code that is excised as you created an MCVE ([MCVE]), but you should state that so people aren't puzzled by it.   Did you validate that the `cd` parameter is valid when you called [`catopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/catopen.html)?  Since `catgets()` takes a `const char *` as its fourth argument, the cast on `dftfmt` is puzzling and superfluous.

Comment: catopen() is not there in code. cd=0x0, i think it could be the error

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement : `if (fp != NULL)` you're checking if fp is NULL, but later in your code you're dereferencing fp + 1:  `if(fp==lp && *(fp+1)=='s')`. If `fp+1` is null, this will throw a segmentation fault.

Comment: I don't see how this line of argument works.  Given that `fp` is a `char *`, if it is not null, it points at a position in the array that contains a `%` symbol.  `*(fp+1)` is the same as `fp[1]` and evaluates to the character after the `%`.  Granted, that might be a null byte (though it probably isn't), the value of `fp+1` is not null and is safe to dereference.

Comment: I agree, but depending on how the dftfmt is formatted it could (if % is the last character) it will be a segmentation fault right? Would help to know which inputs are causing the problem.

Comment: there is no problem with '%'. problem might be with "catopen()" , bcoz they have not opened the msg catalog